# PHP select from statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a php select statement like this:

```
  $select = mysql_query("select * from message where receiver_id = '$receiver_id'and frm_id = '$frm_id' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $id = urlencode(encryptor('encrypt', $result['user_id']));
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }
```

But its not working instead its `select from table where frm_id = $frm_id` only.

Comment: This contains far too little information to know what you expected and what you got. But for one, stop using whatever tutorial you are using right now for learning PHP. mysql_* functions are outdated, deprecated(removed in PHP7) and VERY insecure. Look more into PDO for database operations and paraameter binding.

Comment: you have pass database connection after connecting database.
`mysql_query($query, $connectionid)`

Comment: please avoid use of mysql functions because these are now deprecated in php 7 and this code is not sufficient to get the solution, so please update with full code

Comment: @slax0r or more into `mysqli_*`

Comment: @Gaurav that is optional

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `mysqli_*` is a massive improvement, but why not go directly to the newest technology if you are going to switch or are learning from the beginning?

Comment: To OP: what's the status of this question? if it is solved, pick an answer given that best answered it and accept it. If it isn't, then you should post a comment under (an) answer(s) telling that it didn't solve the question. You have a responsibility also.

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO you can do something like:

```
$id = "Id wanted here";
$conn = new PDO("server", "username", "password");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from `tablename` WHERE `receiver_id` = :id");
$sth->bindParam(':name', $id);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two errors.

1: you are using $result['user_id'] before defining $result.
2: $sql isn't defined.
also i am not sure about encryptor method.

Comment: I am providing an idea to write the code, about encryptor already mentioned in the code, if you can provide me some idea on the code I will provide the solution on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 $select= mysql_query("select * from message where receiver_id = $receiver_id  
 and frm_id = $frm_id ORDER BY id DESC");
```

or

```
$select= mysql_query("select * from message where receiver_id = $receiver_id  
or frm_id = $frm_id ORDER BY id DESC");
```